# syntax highlighting of special text fragment

Tags: javascript, eclipse, syntax-highlighting, backticks, template-literals

I have this within a **Eclipse IDE javascript-editor**:

```
let a = `test ${value}`
```

Within

```
Eclipse->Preferences->Editor->Syntax-Coloring->JavaScript->Template literal
```

I can choose the color of this template literal.

However, I want to set only the **"syntax coloring" of the special fragment "`${}`"**.

**How can I do this with Eclipse?**